# Where is auto merge option?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, object-mode

I can't find the *Auto Merge* option. I looked up tutorials and they all said it should be here somewhere. Can any one please help me find where it is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the options in *Object Mode*. You have to be in *Edit Mode*. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to toggle into *Edit Mode* and you will see the *Auto Merge* option.

[image]